# How to handle lib dependency while compiling?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, static-libraries, unix-ar

Let's say that I have two static libraries : `libA` and `libB` and that `libB` uses `libA`.

For each library `libX` let's say that `hX` is `libX`'s headers's directory and `dX` is `libX`'s file's directory.

Now what happen when a user of `libB` wants to compile a source code `C.c` using `libB` ? Must he  be aware that libB uses libA and so he must type :

```
gcc -IhB -IhA C.c -lA -LdA -lB -LdB
```

Or is there a way to make `libB` automatically 'says' to gcc to use `libA` so a user could type :

```
gcc -IhB -IhA C.c -LdA -lB -LdB
```

?

Comment: I added the [tag:ar] tag because the question crops up frequently in connection with `ar` (static) libraries.  The answer does depend on whether you've got `libA.a` or `libA.so` (or some other shared library suffix), and whether you've got `libB.a` or `libB.so`.  If any one of the libraries is static (`.a`), the answer is "No".  If they're all shared, the answer becomes "Maybe".  Note that `pkg-config` is a system that's intended to help.  Also, the AutoTools (`autoconf` and more particularly `libtool`) may be able to help.

Comment: You should look at the Q&A in the [tag:ar] tag — there aren't many of them, and a number of them are relevant.

Comment: So, if `libB` uses 10 libs which themselves use 10 libs `libB`'s users must know each of the 100 libs ?

Comment: Unless there's overlap (so that it's only 90 distinct libraries), then yes.  Which is where tools like `pkg-config` come in handy.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all static libraries which are required must be listed on the command line. These are just special archive files that provide `.o` files.  Just like you cannot omit required `.o` files, you cannot omit required archives.